# How do I repeat one image a bunch of times to fill up a page in React JSx?

Tags: reactjs, image, for-loop, background, repeat

I'm playing around in React and I was interested in creating an interactive background where this ONE image is repeated (and they rotate, but I figured out how to rotate it). I'm pretty sure there is no way for me to use a for loop also, not sure how to make this happen if it is a background image. I figured I would just use z-index to layer it in the end. So far, I just need help repeating it without using .map()
This is what I have (obviously, it's not working with the for loop):

```
return (
        <div>
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    return (
                        <img
                            key={i}
                            src={circle}
                            alt="circle"
                            className="rotate"
                        />
                    );
                }
            }
        </div>
    );
```

What am I not getting? Shouldn't there be a way to use map without having to copy an image over and over again manually into an array. I feel like that defeats the purpose.

Comment: `I just need help repeating it without using .map()` What's the requirement for this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use map? As far as I'm aware that's the only way to loop inside jsx.

Comment: Is your goal to get a bunch of `<img>` elements in the body? Or you're trying to create an effect of multiple images in the background using CSS. It's not too clear what you want here.

Answer (score 2):

You should use css for that.

`background-repeat` property should be a good solution for your problem.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat

Also, it is not possible to have `for` loops within JSX code.
Check out this lesson to better understand what you can put there:
https://egghead.io/lessons/react-understand-and-use-interpolation-in-jsx

If you have a need to use `for` loop for another purpose this is the way I would suggest doing it:
https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-hermann-uoro8?file=/src/App.js

```
function ElementsList() {
  const elements = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    elements.push(<div key={i}>el {i}</div>);
  }

  return elements;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Generate componets using `for` loop</h1>
      <ElementsList />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I was really just messing around with react and I got curious. The for loop worked, but if I were to use `background-image` with `background-repeat`, how to you get it to rotate on `:hover`?